# Macro to generate multiple struct and trait implementations from parameters

Tags: rust, macro-rules

I'm trying to create a macro using `macro_rules!` that would generate a series of `struct`s along with implementations for a given trait.

A sample of what I've tried:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! a_tree {
    ($name: literal, $fruit: literal) => {
        pub struct $name;
        impl FruitTree for $name {
            fn expected_fruit() -> f64 {
                println!("the {} tree should produce {} fruit", $name, $fruit);
                20 * $fruit
            }
        }
    };
}

pub trait FruitTree {
    fn expected_fruit() -> f64;
}

a_tree![Apple, 1];
a_tree![Cherry, 20];
a_tree![Plum, 10];
a_tree![Orange, 1.2];
```

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d941e873b4e379df8c6a344ea08799e5)

I'm not sure this can be done. I don't necessarily need the `println!` reference to `$name`, if that's a`type` instead of a `literal`. But I didn't get it to work like that either.

What I would want as an output for each struct would be along these lines:

```rust
pub struct Apple;

impl FruitTree for Apple {
     fn expected_fruit() -> f64 {
         println!("the {} tree should produce fruit with a ratio of {}", "Apple", 1);
         20 * 1
     }
}
```

Alternatively, I could declare all the structs beforehand and have the macro generate only the trait implementations, but I'd only do this as a last resort.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out.

The [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7468467899bcc2bb0ecb4b40883fa005)

A few changes were required:

- used `ident` instead of `ty` or `literal` for `$name`
- added `[derive(Debug)]` to the generated struct to allow printing
- fixed some `f64` conversions
- added usage example in `main()`

Thank you!